# Performance impact of generating Content Descriptions for TextViews

Tags: android, performance

I have a lot of dynamically generated TextViews (being fed to a list array adapter), and each of their text contains a summary of a lot of small information. In an effort to improve UI, I used some styling when displaying information, like so:

```
(4 Votes) ☬ [tag1] [java] [regex] ☬ 2 min ago ☬ author ☬ 245 points
```

This line is constructed using a StringBuilder. This line (let's say) looks nice, but not friendly to accessibility tools such as "Google Talk Back". It reads like so: "four votes unknown character bracket tag one close bracket..."

So to fix that, I'm generating another string and set it for content description, like so:

*Asked by "author", who has "245" reputation points, received "4 votes" since "two minutes ago", these are the tags: "tag1", "java", "regex".*

This line would also be generated using StringBuilder, essentially doubles my run-time.

I'm asking:

Is this really doubling my run-time? Is it worth it? Obviously only a very small percentage of people would need accessibility tools, but looks like I'm sacrificing everyone else's CPU cycles.

If it indeed has a negative impact on performance, how can I improve it? Is there a way to detect whether "Talk Back" is used? Is android smart enough to detect this itself, and ignore `setContentDescription()` line?

Comment: Are you displaying this in a ListView?

Comment: @JDJ Yes, I'm displaying it in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its worth worrying about unless your app has performance issues.  But it you do, you can always turn it on or off based on if any accessibility settings are turned on. You can check for enables accessibility apps in Secure Settings.